# Deleting using offsets deletes the wrong item

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, swiftui

I want to do a to do list which, in the main view, sorts all tasks by date, priority and completion.

The problem I'm facing is, when I delete a task using  .onDelete(perform: deleteTasks) and this delete function

```
    private func deleteTasks(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        tasks.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        saveTasksToUserDefaults()
        tasks.sort(by: <)
  
    }
```

Wrong row gets deleted in the view.

I assume this is because the array I delete from (tasks) isn't synced with the view.

```
NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(sortedTasksByDay, id: \.self) { day in
                    if !isOtherDatesHidden || Calendar.current.isDateInToday(day) {
                        Section(header: Text(day.formattedDate)) {
                            ForEach(tasksForDay(day)) { task in
                                if !isTaskHidden(task) {
                                    TaskRowView(task: task)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            toggleTaskCompletion(task)
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteTasks)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

I've tried to sort the array using the same logic as I use when displaying the tasks in the view

```
    static func < (lhs: TaskItem, rhs: TaskItem) -> Bool {
        if lhs.date != rhs.date {
            // Sort by date, oldest date first
            return lhs.date < rhs.date
        } else if lhs.priority != rhs.priority {
            // If dates are the same, sort by priority
            return lhs.priority < rhs.priority
        } else if lhs.isCompleted != rhs.isCompleted {
            // If dates and priority are the same, sort by completion status
            return lhs.isCompleted && !rhs.isCompleted
        } else {
            // If dates, priority, and completion status are the same, sort by task name
            return lhs.taskName < rhs.taskName
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Please help.

Comment: You are deleting from a property `tasks` but this isn’t what you use in your ForEach which means you _don’t_ have a single source of truth and this is hurting you now. Try to refactor your code so you use the same property for both looping/displaying and deleting

Comment: Unrelated but you can write the sort method in one line `return (lhs.date, lhs.priority, lhs.isCompleted, lhs.taskName) < (rhs.date, rhs.priority, rhs.isCompleted, rhs.taskName)`